# Configuring Eclipse/PyDev to use the Python interpreter of my virtual machine

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running some Python code from a virtual machine but I want to use Eclipse/PyDev as an IDE on the host machine. Is there a way to configure Eclipse so that it will use the Python interpreter and the packages of the virtual machine? Those are different from the ones installed on the host machine.
Also, I am not sure on how to have access to the Python interpreter on the virtual machine. I am using a mod version of Ubuntu on Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

If both machines are in the same OS or near, you can:

- Mount the file system of the hosted into the host.
- Go to Eclipse preferences => PyDev => Interpreter - Python => new
- Get the Python executable on the mounted filesystem
- Validate
- Go to properties of your project
- Pydev - Interpreter/Gramar
- Select the newly created interpreter.

You may check for [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) if you want to work with the virtual machine down.

Comment: What do you mean by mount the file system of the hosted into the host. I can only see the virtual machine files that is the vbox and the vmdk file. The virtual machine runs a command-line version of Ubuntu and the host is OS X 10.8. The file system type is 'vboxsf' when I type df -T

Comment: set somthing like samba or ssh in the virtual host and then mount it in the host machin. or with virtualbox, I remember that you can mount it naturaly with virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use [remote debugging](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) when VM python interpreter connecting to your host IDE python debugger. They are communicating and IDE warn VM interpreter about breakpoints.

**Note**: source on IDE side should be the same as on VM otherwise breakpoints would be misplaced.